# Camera preview is upside down

Tags: android, android-camera

I have an application which uses the camera of an android device. The activity which takes the picture can not be rotated, it is displayed only in portrait. 
On most devices this code works fine:

```
int degrees = 0;
int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                 .getRotation();
int degrees = 0;
         switch (rotation) {
             case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
             case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
             case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
             case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
         }
int result;
         if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
             result = (cameraInfo.orientation + degrees) % 360;
             result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
         } else {  // back-facing
             result = (cameraInfo.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
         } camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
```

but on a device (DMTECH 725H, a 7" tablet, with only a front camera) the preview is displayed upside down. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Does this device correctly set `cameraInfo.facing` to `CAMERA_FACING_FRONT`, or it lies that the camera faces back?

Comment: I don't know, I could not debug the application on the device, but I tried to rotate the camera both 90 and 270 degrees and the result is the same

Comment: I have the same issue with camera in Nexus 5X (6.0.1)

Answer (score 2):

The reason of wrong camera rotation can be in unusual orientation of sensor, as mentioned in [this support issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=191210#c4). And you also should use `camera2` package instead of `android.hardware.Camera`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    boolean isLandscape = newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;

    int degrees = 0;
    switch (mDisplay.getRotation()){
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            degrees = isLandscape? 0 : 90;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            degrees = isLandscape? 0 : 270;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            degrees = isLandscape? 180 : 270;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            degrees = isLandscape? 180 : 90;
            break;
    }
    cameraManager.rotateDisplay(degrees, isLandscape);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this solution is not working for me, because my orientation will never be lanscape.

Comment: you wrote it, but if you don't set the activity's attribute `android:screenOrientation="nosensor"` in `AndroidManifest.xml` you have to manage the landscape orientation and change the degree accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the perfect solution. But do refer it,Hope it works for you :)

android.hardware.Camera.setDisplayOrientation

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html

and

android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.setRotation

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html